# What is the best way to check if a website is using all the JS code included?

Tags: javascript, testing, refactoring, software-quality

I am working on a big website with lots of legacy code in it and I really would like to do some clean up as I know for sure that many JS libraries are included, but not used anymore. Obviously there is also custom code.
Unfortunately they do not have any functional testing in place, no documentation and the team'members are all pretty new and no one seems to know anything, a nightmare.

I really do not understand how people can do something like that. There is really no respect or "programmers-code" like: do not leave shit behind you because another programmer like you will have to deal with it after!!!

Our job is awesome and I feel lucky to do it, but lack of respect makes me crazy.

How would you go about it? Do you know any tool that could help in this situations?

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see why this is off topic. _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Comment: I don't agree. Tools are only a part of the answer. I do have a problem that I explained and the most important thing I need and I asked is to suggest a way to approach this problem then yes, tools help too usually.

Comment: At least now you know why if this question is voted down

Comment: `libraries.forEach(function(library) {libary.remove(); if (site.fail()) { library.insert(); }});` :p

Comment: yeah, I know.....but I am so frustrated that I was hoping to get anything! :)

Comment: Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174988/detect-linked-unused-files-and-unused-javascript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136738/find-dead-javascript-code, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167663/is-there-a-tool-to-remove-unused-methods-in-javascript